# Xcode has slowed to a CRAWL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

Took about a two week break from development and came back this week to hit it hard again.  xCode is CRAWLING.  When it opens it takes FOREVER - 5+ minutes - and then every time I click on anything in the GUI the "cursor colorwheel" spins for 2+ minutes.  I tried deleting my `.xcodeproj` file with no effect.  Been reading various posts and the net but can't find anything that improves my situation.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Xcode completely and re-installing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to check I would use Time Machine and go back in time a while, then check Xcode again. If this happens with all projects - even with a new one - then certainly there is sth wrong in general. Check your HD and other progs, also check with activity meter if Xcode is really doing sth.

Anyway, I am currently working on an app with about 200k line and about 15 MB target size. I can use Xcode 4.2 without any delay.

ps once before with XCode 4.0 I experienced sth similar, however, even with a much smaller app. After even trying with Apple support it turned out that for some reason my installation was corrupt and could not be cleaned up. I had to install another Version of Xcode than everything was OK again.

Answer (score 1):

While Justin provided a really good list to start with, I'd like to add something that I think can instantly improve your Xcode and Mac OS X performance (after some re-installation effort, though):

- **get an upgrade to a good, fast SSD drive!**

From my friends' experience it should give better results than upgrade to 8GB of RAM. However  a combo of 8GB and fast SSD is be the best option to go.

Answer (score 0):

some things to help you get started:

- keep with the official releases (read: no betas).
- make sure you have enough RAM (8GB w/ Xc4 is a good minimum for me) and a fast drive.
- revert to 10.6
- revert to Xcode 3
- reduce project interdependencies
- reduce header dependencies (faster indexing and compile times)
- disable live issues (Xc4)
- clear your live search fields (this alone can block UI and builds for minutes).
- file bugs
- try running it in 32-bit (garbage collection consumes a lot of time, and it will reduce the total amount of memory required).
- provide more details of what Xcode is doing that it requires so much time (sample)

Comment: 8GB RAM? I'm going to need an upgrade!

Comment: yes, because 4GB is not enough. the newer clang compilers can use a lot less memory, which is great. Xcode, instruments, etc do consume a ton so Xc3->Xc4 consumes more total memory for my typical uses.

Answer (score 0):

That's not normal.  Sample it and find out where it's spending all that time.

Comment: in my experience, it's quite common in projects of medium or high complexity.

Comment: Then you need to follow the same advice.  The gui shouldn't be stalling out like that, regardless of the size of the project.  I use Xcode 4 every day on projects with hundreds of source files and a dozen targets.

Comment: i have. i've lost days directly and indirectly; filing, and responding to bug reports.